# Display Php Array : Line & Column

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with displaying php array.

I want to display results in horizontal & vertical line & column

SQL :

```
$bdd->query("SELECT DISTINCT sk.keyword AS keyword, sk.id_keyword, sk.search, su.url, suc.id_concurrent, suc.url_concurrent, skr.position, skr.date

    FROM seo_keywords_user AS sku           
    LEFT JOIN seo_keywords AS sk ON sku.id_keyword=sk.id_keyword            
    LEFT JOIN seo_users AS su ON su.id=sku.id_user          
    LEFT JOIN seo_users_concurrent AS suc ON suc.id_user = sku.id_user          
    LEFT JOIN seo_keywords_rank AS skr ON skr.id_concurrent = suc.id_concurrent AND skr.id_keyword =sk.id_keyword 
    
    WHERE sku.id_user='".$_SESSION['id']."'         
    AND skr.id_concurrent = suc.id_concurrent
    
");
$ranking = $bdd->fetchAllObject();
```

> ```
> <table id="demo-dtable-03" class="table table-striped" style="text-align:center">
>     <thead>
>         <tr>
>             <th style="text-align: center">Keyword</th>
>             <th style="border-right: 1px solid black; text-align: center"># search</th>
>             <th style="text-align: center">Website 1</th>
>             <th style="text-align: center">Website x</th>
>             <th style="text-align: center">Website x</th>
>             <th style="text-align: center">Website x</th>
>         </tr>
>     </thead>
>     <tbody>
>         <?php foreach($ranking as $rank): ?>
>             <tr>                                          
>                 <td style="background-color: white;border-bottom: none;  text-align: center"><?php echo $rank->keyword; ?></td>
>                 <td style="text-align: center; background-color: white; border-right: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $rank->search; ?></td>
>                 <td><?php echo $rank->url_concurrent; ?></td>
>                 <td><?php echo $rank->position; ?></td>
>                 <td></td>
>                 <td></td>
>             </tr> 
>         <?php endforeach; ?>          
>     </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: Seems you need to use another query. Ready about GROUP BY https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/group-by-modifiers.html You might also use a subquery.

Comment: Please post germane portions of remote websites here in case the link goes away in the future.